Change login timeout period?
When a user fails to enter a password they receive an increasingly long delay between login attempts.
By default it seems this retry failure increases to rather unergonomic values, for example you can get locked out of your machine for 8 hours.
Is there a way modify the timeout behavior?

I would hope this security feature isn't easily bypassed. Wouldn't it be better to follow a known password reset procedure if you fail to enter a password twice or at most three times?

https://eclecticlight.co/2024/02/28/solving-login-password-problems/

If your IT department needs better options than waiting, point them at this resource for advice and training.

https://www.macadmins.org/
https://github.com/macadmins/escrow-buddy


its a configuration and not a bypass

The configuration is meant to deter brute force attacks @Mikhail on which build and version of macOS do you seek to change the configuration?

Lets go with MacOS
14.4.1 (23E224)

most systems don't use an 8 hour + lock out that local it departments can't reset.

Aah - now that avenue has lots of options for IT to add second accounts, unique recovery keys, shared recovery keys, validated backup, reset and MDM unlock and lock commands. With some preparation and process (or training), you never have to sit for a timeout  @Mikhail
